# Seeking LAG LiDAR Analysis GUI installation guide?

Tags: installation, lidar, debian

Does anyone know how do I install LAG lidar Analysis Gui?
[LAG by arsf](http://arsf.github.io/lag/)

This is my situation: I'm using debian 8 test. I installed this library: boost (yes) * GTKmm (yes) * GTKGLextmm (yes) * GThread (yes) * libgeotiff (no) * laslib (yes with Lastool) * lidarquadtree (no). After I Tried this: 1) Install the binutils-gold package before compiling but it returned an error (dependency not...). I stopped here.

Comment: In the package there are Lastools executables, very simple and good tools to do analysis. For the simple visualization is also fugroviewer http://www.fugroviewer.com/

Comment: Hello, I'm using debian 8 test. I installed this library: boost (yes) * GTKmm (yes) * GTKGLextmm (yes) * GThread (yes) * libgeotiff (no) * laslib (yes with Lastool) * lidarquadtree (no). After I Tried this: 1) Install the binutils-gold package before compiling but it returned an error (dependency not...). I stopped here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing binutils-gold is only required if compilation fails (this has been the case under Ubuntu, I'm not sure about Debian). After installing the required prerequisites you should be able to get LAG working using the following steps:

- If you haven't already installed autotools:

  ```
  apt-get install autotools
  ```
- LAG has recently been updated so the patched version of LAStools are no longer included you need to download the ARSF fork from https://github.com/arsf/LAStools and run

  ```
  make
  make install
  ```
- Prior to installing LAG you need to install lidarquadtree from the 'lidarquadtree' folder the LAG source using:

  ```
  libtoolize && autoheader && aclocal && automake --add-missing && autoconf
  ./configure
  make
  make install
  ```

After this you should be able to compile LAG.

Comment: Thanks, Now I use whitebox. I tried to install LAG but in debian there are others dependences.